# Its a oracle stored procedure where i m getting "PLS-00403:"

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to execute an Oracle stored procedure for my project. But I was getting an error

> PLS-00403: expression <> cannot be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement

This error is coming for all the input parameters declared.

This is my code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CASHPROJECTIONS_ACC_STG
(
   P_INVESTMENT_OFFICER IN VARCHAR2,
    P_ADMINISTRATOR_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
    P_ACCOUNT_NUMBER IN INTEGER,
    P_ACCOUNT_ODFLAG IN VARCHAR2,
    P_USD_PT_ODFLAG_NEW IN VARCHAR2,
    P_ACCT_SWEEP_COVERED IN VARCHAR2,
    P_USD_PT_SWEEP_COVERED IN VARCHAR2,
    P_RUNDATE OUT DATE,
    P_RELATIONSHIP_NAME OUT VARCHAR2,
    P_PORTFOLIO_NUMBER OUT INTEGER,
    P_PORTFOLIO_NAME OUT VARCHAR2,
    P_NETTING_FOR_OVERDRAFTS OUT VARCHAR2,
    P_NETTING_FOR_SWEEP OUT VARCHAR2,
    P_SUMMARY_DESCRIPTION OUT VARCHAR2,
    P_INCOME_BASE OUT FLOAT,
    P_USD_INC_DAILY_BAL OUT FLOAT,
    P_PRINCIPAL_BASE OUT FLOAT,
    P_USD_PRIN_DAILY_BAL OUT FLOAT,
    P_ACCT_BALANCE OUT FLOAT,
    P_SWEEP_PT1 OUT FLOAT,
    P_SWEEP_TOTAL OUT FLOAT,
    P_SWEEP_RESTRICTED OUT FLOAT,
    P_SWEEP_AVAILABLE_BALANCE OUT FLOAT,
    P_SWEEP_PT1_ASSET_NM OUT VARCHAR2

)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT  
   RUNDATE
,INVESTMENT_OFFICER
,ADMINISTRATOR_NAME
,RELATIONSHIP_NAME
,ACCOUNT_NUMBER
,PORTFOLIO_NUMBER
,PORTFOLIO_NAME
,NETTING_FOR_OVERDRAFTS
,NETTING_FOR_SWEEP
,SUMMARY_DESCRIPTION
,INCOME_BASE
,USD_INC_DAILY_BAL
,PRINCIPAL_BASE
,USD_PRIN_DAILY_BAL
,ACCT_BALANCE
,SWEEP_PT1
,SWEEP_TOTAL
,SWEEP_RESTRICTED
,SWEEP_AVAILABLE_BALANCE
,ACCOUNT_ODFLAG
,ACCT_SWEEP_COVERED
,USD_PT_ODFLAG_NEW
,USD_PT_SWEEP_COVERED
,SWEEP_PT1_ASSET_NM
into
P_RUNDATE
,P_INVESTMENT_OFFICER
,P_ADMINISTRATOR_NAME
,P_RELATIONSHIP_NAME
,P_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
,P_PORTFOLIO_NUMBER
,P_PORTFOLIO_NAME
,P_NETTING_FOR_OVERDRAFTS
,P_NETTING_FOR_SWEEP
,P_SUMMARY_DESCRIPTION
,P_INCOME_BASE
,P_USD_INC_DAILY_BAL
,P_PRINCIPAL_BASE
,P_USD_PRIN_DAILY_BAL
,P_ACCT_BALANCE
,P_SWEEP_PT1
,P_SWEEP_TOTAL
,P_SWEEP_RESTRICTED
,P_SWEEP_AVAILABLE_BALANCE
,P_ACCOUNT_ODFLAG
,P_ACCT_SWEEP_COVERED
,P_USD_PT_ODFLAG_NEW
,P_USD_PT_SWEEP_COVERED
,P_SWEEP_PT1_ASSET_NM



   FROM FTCI_CASHPROJECTIONS_ACC_STG CPAS 
   WHERE CPAS.INVESTMENT_OFFICER = P_INVESTMENT_OFFICER
   AND CPAS.ADMINISTRATOR_NAME = P_ADMINISTRATOR_NAME
   AND CPAS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = P_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
   AND CPAS.ACCOUNT_ODFLAG = P_ACCOUNT_ODFLAG
   AND CPAS.USD_PT_ODFLAG_NEW = P_USD_PT_ODFLAG_NEW
   AND CPAS.ACCT_SWEEP_COVERED = P_ACCT_SWEEP_COVERED
    AND CPAS.USD_PT_SWEEP_COVERED = P_USD_PT_SWEEP_COVERED;
END;
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I am trying to execute an Oracle stored procedure for my project. But I was getting an error as "PLS-00403: expression <FILEDNAME> cannot be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement".This error is coming for all the input parameters declared

Comment: are you using oracle or mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several columns of your SELECT statement are mapped to these parameters:

```
P_INVESTMENT_OFFICER IN VARCHAR2,
P_ADMINISTRATOR_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
P_ACCOUNT_NUMBER IN INTEGER,
P_ACCOUNT_ODFLAG IN VARCHAR2,
P_USD_PT_ODFLAG_NEW IN VARCHAR2,
P_ACCT_SWEEP_COVERED IN VARCHAR2,
P_USD_PT_SWEEP_COVERED IN VARCHAR2,
```

You have defined them as IN parameters, therefore you cannot assign values to them. This is the meaning of the error message:

> PLS-00403: expression  cannot be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement

There is a choice of two solutions.

1. Do not assign to those parameters.
2. Change them to be IN OUT parameters.

In this case the first solution is the correct choice.  The calling program passes those values in, to restrict the query. So it already knows those values and doesn't need the called program to reflect them back. Defining a parameter as IN OUT implies the called program may change the passed value.

---

> can u tell the first point in detail. But I need the in parameters

It's really not hard. You keep the IN parameters for filtering the query but you remove them from the projection on the query and the matching INTO clause. Like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CASHPROJECTIONS_ACC_STG
(
   P_INVESTMENT_OFFICER IN VARCHAR2,
    P_ADMINISTRATOR_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
    P_ACCOUNT_NUMBER IN INTEGER,
    P_ACCOUNT_ODFLAG IN VARCHAR2,
    P_USD_PT_ODFLAG_NEW IN VARCHAR2,
    P_ACCT_SWEEP_COVERED IN VARCHAR2,
    P_USD_PT_SWEEP_COVERED IN VARCHAR2,
    P_RUNDATE OUT DATE,
    P_RELATIONSHIP_NAME OUT VARCHAR2,
    P_PORTFOLIO_NUMBER OUT INTEGER,
    P_PORTFOLIO_NAME OUT VARCHAR2,
    P_NETTING_FOR_OVERDRAFTS OUT VARCHAR2,
    P_NETTING_FOR_SWEEP OUT VARCHAR2,
    P_SUMMARY_DESCRIPTION OUT VARCHAR2,
    P_INCOME_BASE OUT FLOAT,
    P_USD_INC_DAILY_BAL OUT FLOAT,
    P_PRINCIPAL_BASE OUT FLOAT,
    P_USD_PRIN_DAILY_BAL OUT FLOAT,
    P_ACCT_BALANCE OUT FLOAT,
    P_SWEEP_PT1 OUT FLOAT,
    P_SWEEP_TOTAL OUT FLOAT,
    P_SWEEP_RESTRICTED OUT FLOAT,
    P_SWEEP_AVAILABLE_BALANCE OUT FLOAT,
    P_SWEEP_PT1_ASSET_NM OUT VARCHAR2

)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT  
   RUNDATE
,RELATIONSHIP_NAME
,PORTFOLIO_NUMBER
,PORTFOLIO_NAME
,NETTING_FOR_OVERDRAFTS
,NETTING_FOR_SWEEP
,SUMMARY_DESCRIPTION
,INCOME_BASE
,USD_INC_DAILY_BAL
,PRINCIPAL_BASE
,USD_PRIN_DAILY_BAL
,ACCT_BALANCE
,SWEEP_PT1
,SWEEP_TOTAL
,SWEEP_RESTRICTED
,SWEEP_AVAILABLE_BALANCE
,SWEEP_PT1_ASSET_NM
into
P_RUNDATE
,P_RELATIONSHIP_NAME
,P_PORTFOLIO_NUMBER
,P_PORTFOLIO_NAME
,P_NETTING_FOR_OVERDRAFTS
,P_NETTING_FOR_SWEEP
,P_SUMMARY_DESCRIPTION
,P_INCOME_BASE
,P_USD_INC_DAILY_BAL
,P_PRINCIPAL_BASE
,P_USD_PRIN_DAILY_BAL
,P_ACCT_BALANCE
,P_SWEEP_PT1
,P_SWEEP_TOTAL
,P_SWEEP_RESTRICTED
,P_SWEEP_AVAILABLE_BALANCE
,P_SWEEP_PT1_ASSET_NM
FROM FTCI_CASHPROJECTIONS_ACC_STG CPAS 
   WHERE CPAS.INVESTMENT_OFFICER = P_INVESTMENT_OFFICER
   AND CPAS.ADMINISTRATOR_NAME = P_ADMINISTRATOR_NAME
   AND CPAS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = P_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
   AND CPAS.ACCOUNT_ODFLAG = P_ACCOUNT_ODFLAG
   AND CPAS.USD_PT_ODFLAG_NEW = P_USD_PT_ODFLAG_NEW
   AND CPAS.ACCT_SWEEP_COVERED = P_ACCT_SWEEP_COVERED
    AND CPAS.USD_PT_SWEEP_COVERED = P_USD_PT_SWEEP_COVERED;
END;
```

Comment: I am new to writing store procedure .. can u tell the first point in detail. But I need the in parameters

Answer (score -1):

The reason behind the error is that you are fetching values in input parameters using `INTO` in `Stored procedure`

i.e.

```
P_INVESTMENT_OFFICER IN VARCHAR2,
P_ADMINISTRATOR_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
P_ACCOUNT_NUMBER IN INTEGER,
P_ACCOUNT_ODFLAG IN VARCHAR2,
```

Instead of fetching values in these parameter, I would like to suggest use local variable and fetch values in it.

e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CASHPROJECTIONS_ACC_STG
(
   P_INVESTMENT_OFFICER IN VARCHAR2,
    P_ADMINISTRATOR_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
    P_ACCOUNT_NUMBER IN INTEGER,
    P_ACCOUNT_ODFLAG IN VARCHAR2,
    --- Other variables comes here   

)
IS
  L_INVESTMENT_OFFICER VARCHAR2;
    L_ADMINISTRATOR_NAME VARCHAR2;
    L_ACCOUNT_NUMBER INTEGER;
    L_ACCOUNT_ODFLAG VARCHAR2;
    -- Do for the rest parameters

BEGIN
   SELECT  
   RUNDATE
,INVESTMENT_OFFICER
,ADMINISTRATOR_NAME
,ACCOUNT_ODFLAG
,ACCOUNT_NUMBER
-- Rest column names comes here
into
P_RUNDATE
,L_INVESTMENT_OFFICER
,L_ADMINISTRATOR_NAME
,L_ACCOUNT_ODFLAG
,L_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
--- Rest Local variables comes here
   FROM FTCI_CASHPROJECTIONS_ACC_STG CPAS 
   WHERE CPAS.INVESTMENT_OFFICER = P_INVESTMENT_OFFICER
   AND CPAS.ADMINISTRATOR_NAME = P_ADMINISTRATOR_NAME
   AND CPAS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = P_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
   AND CPAS.ACCOUNT_ODFLAG = P_ACCOUNT_ODFLAG
   AND CPAS.USD_PT_ODFLAG_NEW = P_USD_PT_ODFLAG_NEW
   AND CPAS.ACCT_SWEEP_COVERED = P_ACCT_SWEEP_COVERED
    AND CPAS.USD_PT_SWEEP_COVERED = P_USD_PT_SWEEP_COVERED;
END;
```

Comment: Do you think this code will compile? Because I don't.

Comment: Hi Raj, when I ran the code in the similar way below is the error I m getting "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IN" when expecting one of the following:     constant exception <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref    char time timestamp interval date binary national character    nchar 
Errors: check compiler log"

Comment: Hi @APC,edited my stored proc, it was happened due to copying Input variables

Comment: I know why it happened. You still haven't fixed the variable declarations, so it still wouldn't compil.